# Saving time with prepared statements

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Below i am searching for five different videos and receiving the genre of each of them. Is there a way that i can combine all five together into one query to make my code more efficient? I am certain there is a way, its just that i am struggling with syntax.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Genre FROM videos Where VideoId = ?"); 
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$item1);// Video one
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Genre1);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Genre FROM videos Where VideoId = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$item2); // video two
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Genre2);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Genre FROM videos Where VideoId = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$item3);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Genre3);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Genre FROM videos Where VideoId = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$item4);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Genre4);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Genre FROM videos Where VideoId = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$item5);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Genre5);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Uhm, the idea behind prepared statements is, to prepare it only once, then use the same statement with different parameters...just as a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $Genres = array();
 $items = array($item1, $item2, $item3,$item4,$item5);
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Genre FROM videos Where VideoId = ? ");

 foreach ($items as $index => $item) {

    $stmt->bind_param('s',$item);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Genres[$index]);
    $stmt->fetch(); 
 } 

 $stmt->close();
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but wouldn't be better if the prepare was outside the for loop?